# Breaking out of an infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

Is there a way to break out of an infinite loop while it's running without using Ctrl + C? I would like to implement such a method in other programs. Like in this example program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int x = 0;
     for(;;)
         cout << x;
}
```

is there a way to keep the for loop going but break it with some key at any time. I should also explain I understand using break;, but I want the loop to keep going. If I use a break condition like this, the for-loop would stop and wait for a response.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int x = 0;
     for(;;)
     {
         cout << x;
         if(getch()=='n')
                break;
     }  

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Find some condition that you wish to [break](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) out of the loop when encountered then use the break keyword:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     int x = 0;
     for(;;)
         cout << x;
         if(/* break condition*/){
             break;
         }
}
```

There's nothing stopping you from implementing the break condition by detecting a particular keyboard input from a user.

EDIT: From your edited question it appears you want to have loop continue running all the time and not stopping waiting for user input. The only way I can think of doing this is to spawn a new thread that listens for user input that alters a variable that gets detected in the break condition of your main thread.

If you have access to c++11 and the new thread library you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

bool break_condition = false;

void looper(){
    for(;;){
        std::cout << "loop running" << std::endl;
        if(break_condition){
            break;
        }
    }
}

void user_input(){
    if(std::cin.get()=='n'){
        break_condition = true;
    }
}

int main(){
    //create a thread for the loop and one for listening for input
    std::thread loop_thread(looper);
    std::thread user_input_thread(user_input);

    //synchronize threads
    loop_thread.join();
    user_input_thread.join();

    std::cout << "loop successfully broken out of" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you do decide to take a threading approach be careful as there's issues in multithreaded code that don't exist in single threaded code and they can sometimes be really nasty.

Comment: I understand this method, but it stops the for-loop as it waits for a response. I would like the for-loop to continue while the break-condition waits outside of it.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean when you say "I would like the for-loop to continue while the break-condition waits outside of it" ?

Comment: write a signal handler to set the break condition.

Comment: Every time the for-loop repeats, it displays 0. But the break condition waits for a response, so I would have to press a key each time I want the for-loop to repeat. I would like for the loop to keep repeating without the break condition stopping it.

Comment: use the signal function to register a function to handle the ^C. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html#Basic-Signal-Handling

Comment: @HughB This question is tagged C++. You are suggesting a platform dependent solution.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry - the gnu reference was mainly to illustrate signal handling. I'm using signal() the same way on a windows app (built with vis studio 2010) that allows me to tell when someone shut's down the app. My app basically while(!done) { do stuff } then the sig handler sets done to true when term signal is received.

Comment: @shuttle87: This should be `std::atomic<bool> break_condition = false;`